# регулярные выражения python, поиск строк со служебными символами

Tags: регулярные-выражения, python-3.x

Есть список с номерами телефонов, в формате: `['(232)6896232', ....]` которые извлечены из текста. В этом же тексте я хочу найти позицию этих номеров в тексте.

Использую `re.search()`. Не могу найти номера, из-за символов `(`, `)`

Как мне настроить функцию, чтобы решить проблему?
Спасибо!

Пример кода!

Пример номера телефона из списка: '(343) 202-07-05'

## Функция пробегает список с номерами телефонов и ищет позицию каждого номера в исходном списке:

```
'def positions(regulars, text):
    positions = []
    for item in regulars:
        pos = re.search(item, text)
        if pos is not None:
            positions.append({'start': pos.start(), 'end': pos.end()})
    return positions'
```

Comment: Можно просто заменить `string.replace('(', '').replace(')', '')` или читать доки `re`

Comment: приведите пример исходного текста с номерами телефонов и код в котором вы выбираете эти номера...

Comment: Из вопроса може показаться, что надо просто (без всяких регэкспов), по каждому номеру поискать его в тексте  функцией find(), наверное в цикле, чтобы найти все случаи.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае можно не использовать регулярные выражения, можно найти индекс вхождения телефонного номера с помощью `find()` / `index()`, а конечная позиция — это начальная позиция + длина номера.

Если нужно использовать регулярное выражения, нужно использовать `re.escape`, чтобы экранировать специальные метасимволы, которыми являются круглые скобки (и некоторые другие).

Пример обоих подходов:

```
import re
phones = ['(232)6896232', '(123)4567891']
def positions_regex(regulars, text):
    positions = []
    for item in regulars:
        pos = re.search(re.escape(item), text) # re.escape!
        if pos:
            positions.append({'start': pos.start(), 'end': pos.end()})
    return positions

def positions_literal(regulars, text):
    positions = []
    for item in regulars:
        pos = text.index(item)
        if pos > -1:
            positions.append({'start': pos, 'end': pos+len(item) })
    return positions

s = "(232)6896232 --- (123)4567891"
print(positions_regex(phones, s))
print(positions_literal(phones, s))
```

См. [демо онлайн](https://ideone.com/DLSvfi). В обоих случаях результат — `[{'start': 0, 'end': 12}, {'start': 17, 'end': 29}]`.

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @AlexModestov Если ответ помог, пожалуйста, отметьте его как правильный.